# Webshopapps Matrix Rates - extension for shipping not working

Tags: ajax, magento-1.7

I am using this Magento extension and by some orders the shipping is not calculated. Interesting is i can see the name of the shipping on my order bill, but the amount is not calculated. It looks like this:

Shipping LocalGTR - 0.00€ (actually it should be Shipping LocalGTR - 4.90€ ).

I can't figure it out why this happens to only just some orders. I have multiple orders per hour and this happens one or twice a week that by some customers the shipping is not calculated.

Can it be an AJAX problem or old browsers problem?

Did anyone have the same problem with this extension?